# App on App Store - This bundle is invalid The key UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in the

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have an app on the App Store and I want to submit a new version. I archived the app and uploaded it to itunnesconnect and at the same time I got an email from them -

> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "School Class Reminder". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery: 
>   This bundle is invalid - The key UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in the Info.plist may not contain values that would prevent this application from running on devices that were supported by previous versions. Refer to .... for additional information: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1623/_index.html
>   After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.

On my app on App Store it says that is compatible with iPhone, iPad and iPod. In this new build I just uploaded I set `telephony` in `Required device capabilities` in order to make the app only installable on iPhones but now I got this email. Is it safe to upload the new version of the app with this build regarding the email I got ?

Comment: It is not a duplicate ! My question here is if I can upload this build on the App Store safely and I am not questioning compatibility as you are saying.

Comment: I don't know what to mean by "safe". The build will simply not upload successfully and appear in iTunesConnect due to this issue. You cannot release a  version of an app that is compatible with fewer devices than the previous version.

Comment: Then if you don't know what the question means why do you mark it as duplicate ? "Safe" means will the app install on iPhones or not.

Comment: The app will install on iPhones, but that build  can't  be made available on the store, since you can't upload it, therefore the question of "safe" makes no sense. You have to address your underlying issue, as per the duplicate, and remove the telephony device requirement.

Comment: If your new version has features that only work on a phone then you will need to deal with that at runtime since you can not prevent any new version being installed on iPod touches or iPads.